# Mongodb query: find documents having all elements of array in a given range

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection whose documents have this structure

```
{
   ...
   "ts": [NumberLong("5"), NumberLong("7")]
   ...
}
```

where `ts` is an array of two `Long` elements, where the second is strictly bigger than the first one.

I want to retrieve all documents where all the elements of the array `ts` are within a range (bigger than a value but smaller than another).

Suppose the range is between `4` and `9`; I am trying this query, but I find unexpected results:

```
db.segments.find({$nor: [{ "ts": {$gt:9, $lt:4}}]}).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed number of array length then you can use the index of array in query part,

```
db.segments.find({
  "ts.0": { $gt: 4 },
  "ts.1": { $lt: 9 }
}).toArray()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RnkaZmX_k7V)